# Cropper js aspect ratio button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Cropper.js aspect ratio buttons not working. Whenever I tried to upload an image and try to press the 16:9 button then my images will be invisible and not cropped and reinitiate. after that when I again select the image at that time I will see effect of my button.*

> https://fengyuanchen.github.io/jquery-cropper/

**Cropper-init.js**

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    var console = window.console || { log: function () {} };
    var $image = $('#image');
    var $download = $('#download');
    var $dataX = $('#dataX');
    var $dataY = $('#dataY');
    var $dataHeight = $('#dataHeight');
    var $dataWidth = $('#dataWidth');
    var $dataRotate = $('#dataRotate');
    var $dataScaleX = $('#dataScaleX');
    var $dataScaleY = $('#dataScaleY');
    var options = {
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          preview: '.img-preview',
          crop: function (e) {
            $dataX.val(Math.round(e.x));
            $dataY.val(Math.round(e.y));
            $dataHeight.val(Math.round(e.height));
            $dataWidth.val(Math.round(e.width));
            $dataRotate.val(e.rotate);
            $dataScaleX.val(e.scaleX);
            $dataScaleY.val(e.scaleY);
          }
        };


    // Tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();


    // Cropper
    $image.on({
      'build.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type);
      },
      'built.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type);
      },
      'cropstart.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'cropmove.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'cropend.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type, e.action);
      },
      'crop.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type, e.x, e.y, e.width, e.height, e.rotate, e.scaleX, e.scaleY);
        $('#img_btn').prop("disabled", false);
      },
      'zoom.cropper': function (e) {
        // console.log(e.type, e.ratio);
      }
    }).cropper(options);


    // Buttons
    if (!$.isFunction(document.createElement('canvas').getContext)) {
      $('button[data-method="getCroppedCanvas"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }

    if (typeof document.createElement('cropper').style.transition === 'undefined') {
      $('button[data-method="rotate"]').prop('disabled', true);
      $('button[data-method="scale"]').prop('disabled', true);
    }


    // Download
    // if (typeof $download[0].download === 'undefined') {
    //   $download.addClass('disabled');
    // }


    // Options
    $('.docs-toggles').on('change', 'input', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var name = $this.attr('name');
      var type = $this.prop('type');
      var cropBoxData;
      var canvasData;

      if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
        return;
      }

      if (type === 'checkbox') {
        options[name] = $this.prop('checked');
        cropBoxData = $image.cropper('getCropBoxData');
        canvasData = $image.cropper('getCanvasData');

        options.built = function () {
          $image.cropper('setCropBoxData', cropBoxData);
          $image.cropper('setCanvasData', canvasData);
        };
      } else if (type === 'radio') {
        options[name] = $this.val();
      }

      $image.cropper('destroy').cropper(options);
    });


    // Methods
    $('.docs-buttons').on('click', '[data-method]', function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var data = $this.data();
      var $target;
      var result;

      if ($this.prop('disabled') || $this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        return;
      }

      if ($image.data('cropper') && data.method) {
        data = $.extend({}, data); // Clone a new one

        if (typeof data.target !== 'undefined') {
          $target = $(data.target);

          if (typeof data.option === 'undefined') {
            try {
              data.option = JSON.parse($target.val());
            } catch (e) {
              // console.log(e.message);
            }
          }
        }

        if (data.method === 'rotate') {
          $image.cropper('clear');
        }

        result = $image.cropper(data.method, data.option, data.secondOption);

        if (data.method === 'rotate') {
          $image.cropper('crop');
        }

        switch (data.method) {
          case 'scaleX':
          case 'scaleY':
            $(this).data('option', -data.option);
            break;

          case 'getCroppedCanvas':
            if (result) {

              // Bootstrap's Modal
              $('#getCroppedCanvasModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(result);

              if (!$download.hasClass('disabled')) {
                $download.attr('href', result.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
              }
            }

            break;
        }

        if ($.isPlainObject(result) && $target) {
          try {
            $target.val(JSON.stringify(result));
          } catch (e) {
            // console.log(e.message);
          }
        }

      }
    });


    // Keyboard
    $(document.body).on('keydown', function (e) {

      if (!$image.data('cropper') || this.scrollTop > 300) {
        return;
      }

      switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', -1, 0);
          break;

        case 38:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 0, -1);
          break;

        case 39:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 1, 0);
          break;

        case 40:
          e.preventDefault();
          $image.cropper('move', 0, 1);
          break;
      }

    });


    // Import image
    var $inputImage = $('.input-image');
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var blobURL;

    if (URL) {
      $inputImage.change(function () {
        var files = this.files;
        var file;

        if (!$image.data('cropper')) {
          return;
        }

        if (files && files.length) {
          file = files[0];

          if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
            blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $image.one('built.cropper', function () {

              // Revoke when load complete
              URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
            }).cropper('reset').cropper('replace', blobURL);
          } else {
            $inputImage.val('');
            $('#formUploadImage').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'inputImage');
            $('#image').cropper('destroy').cropper({
              aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
              viewMode: 1
            });
            window.alert('Please choose an image file.');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $inputImage.prop('disabled', true).parent().addClass('disabled');
    }

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="inputImage" name="inputImage" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="form-control input-image" />

<div class="docs-toggles btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline active">
  <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="aspectRatio0" name="aspectRatio" value="1.7777777777777777">
 <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="aspectRatio: 16 / 9"> 16:9 </span> </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline">
    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="aspectRatio1" name="aspectRatio" value="1.3333333333333333">
      <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="aspectRatio: 4 / 3"> 4:3 </span> </label>
   <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline">
    <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="aspectRatio2" name="aspectRatio" value="1">
         <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="aspectRatio: 1 / 1"> 1:1 </span> </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-outline">
       <input type="radio" class="sr-only" id="aspectRatio3" name="aspectRatio" value="0.6666666666666666">
        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="aspectRatio: 2 / 3"> 2:3 </span> </label>
  </div>
```